# Relocating svg element

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, responsive

I have a main svg image and another small svg image. The goal is to get the location of main image and base on that, "translate" the small image (placing it on a certain point of main image). The problem is by resizing the window all calculations will be lose. Whate's the best solution?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] showing us what you've got now, ideally as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Add a div where you have two svgs you need in it, style div according to window, style svg per your requirements

Comment: it's hard to say without seeing any code. Probably I would put the smaller svg inside the main one as a nested svg or as a symbol. Both svg elements would have a viewBox attribute. The inner one would have also a width and a height. The x and y attributes can be used to place the svg element where needed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.